# iam ConfirmSubscription permissions error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I have an app I am trying to move to a new k8s cluster, having a permissions issue when trying to ConfirmSubscription:

```
"sns confirmation failed. Reason: AuthorizationError: User: arn:aws:sts::-:assumed-role/-/- is not authorized to perform: 
SNS:ConfirmSubscription on resource: arn:aws:sns:-:-:topicname
status code: 403, request id: 000d2844-3a3d-5544-922a-7d9e3db07a16"
```

The app was able to execute a confirm subscription in the old cluster, so I assume it's an IAM issue, but the role policy it's assuming is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "sns:ConfirmSubscription",
    "sns:Subscribe"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:sns:::*"
  ]
}
]
}
```

I haven't been able to diagnose where the IAM issue is.

Comment: Seems suspicious that it says "assumed-role/-/-". Did your previous cluster have something like [`kube2iam`](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam) installed such that requests from containers to AWS API endpoints were proxied through the host which would assume a specific role on behalf of the container?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta the cluster nodes get their instance permissions by assuming iam roles, with the policies attached to the role they assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by fully qualifying the sns topic to which I wanted to confirm subscription:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "sns:ConfirmSubscription",
    "sns:Subscribe"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000:full-topic-name-no-wildcard"
  ]
}
  ]
}
```